# gateway timeout after 60 sec execution at apache2

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, apache2

When I run the script I get a gateway timeout error. My server is apache2. I made the below edit but the error still occurs.

**file : /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini**

```
max_execution_time = 0
max_input_time = -1
memory_limit = 128M
```

**file : /etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 216000
```

Then I restart the **server** and **reboot** the OS, but the error still occurs. How can I can increase the execution time from **60 seconds** to **5 mins**

I am using php and laravel framework in my project.

Here is an image of the error:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Increase that values (be sure that you do that in proper php.ini file):

```
max_execution_time = 0
max_input_time = -1
memory_limit = 258M
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 257M
```

And restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: i already edited them the file is at this path /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: check what php version is used in project: php -v, maybe u use php7.0

Comment: php version is 5.5.9

Comment: look at etc directory and write all directories starting from php, show it

Comment: yeah i look that only one dir is starting from php its **php5**

Comment: check also that values: memory_limit = 258M
    upload_max_filesize = 256M
    post_max_size = 257M

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170752/discussion-between-shahneel-ahmed-and-adam-kozlowski).